# How to derive a model for a recursive situation

Tags: recursion, mathematical-modeling

An animal use 50% of its fat every night, but is able to add $4$ grams to its fat reserve every day. This same animal begin with 3 grams of fat on the first night.

Derive a model for its fat reserve at the beginning of $(t-1)$ night.

I tried to write down first couple nights and find a relation.

Night 1: $3$

Night 2: $3*0.5+4$

Night 3: $(3*0.5+4)*0.5 + 4$

Night 4: $((3*0.5+4)*0.5 + 4)*0.5 + 4$

I feel like I am onto something, but I can't quite get it. Maybe it's my lack of understanding of recursive relationship. I need some help on this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to generalize a pattern, it'll help to have notation for the items in the sequence. For every natural number $t$, let's define $x_t$ to be the fat amount on the beginning of the $t$th night. You've calculated $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4$. Could you write a formula for $x_{100}$ in terms of $x_{99}$? A formula for $x_{t+1}$ in terms of $x_t$? Then you're done. (It looks like you're not required to solve the recurrence relation, just write it down.)

Comment: The question does not allow variable $x$. It seems I have to write without any arbitrary variable not given in the question.

Comment: If your answer has to be in terms of $t$ only, then it sounds like you're expected to solve the recurrence relation. But before you can solve it, you have to write it down, and that requires giving a name to the $t$th element of the sequence. You could call it $x_t$ or $a_t$ or $f(t)$ or "(amount on night $t$)".

Comment: @SirouEwei: I believe what Karl is trying to say is that you can write $f(1)=3$, $f(2)=3*0.5+4$, etc.  Now, say that $f(2) = f(1)*0.5+4$.  Is there a way of writing $f(3)$ in terms of $f(2)$?  You may notice a pattern if you do this, so that you can then write $f(t)$ in terms of $f(t-1)$.  If you can find this pattern, you are one step closer to solving the problem.